# Fact table referencing another fact table?

Tags: sql-server, data-modeling, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

We recently started working on our Data warehouse. We have Technicians, Salespersons, Date, Branch, Customer as our dimensions. We also have transactional tables in OLTP such as Sales Orders, Agreements, Which are referenced to each other in some situations. I'm planning to put sales order, Agreements info in Fact tables. So, that I would like to reference the all the above mentioned dimensions in both fact tables. But, here comes my problem.
Sales orders and service agreements need to referenced with each other. In most cases, Agreements information need to be referenced in Sales orders. Can I reference two fact tables each other in fact table? The sales orders table in OLTP consists Million records, and Agreement table holds half million records(minimum). Can you let me know if I can reference these two in fact table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have something like an AgreementID which can be added to each fact table and then used to drill across? This is a degenerate dimension - a dimension key without a dimension table.

Comment: HI GoogleBoy I agree with Todd... You could use the AgreementID(if you have it) as an external reference id (degenerate dimension). If you have further questions, please feel free to share.

Comment: Thanks Todd for your response, Yes Agreement ID is available. If I make agreement as degenerate dimension, I can only store Agreement ID in Sales Order Fact table right? But I have to store the Agreement complete information also.
Sales Order will consist attributes like (Sales Order ID, Start Date, End Date, Amount, Technician, Sales Person)
Agreement Also consist similar information like (Agreement ID, Name, TemplateID, Agreement Start Date, Agreement End Date, Amount, Tech)
Do you suggest to store this info in separate dimension tables or Two fact tables with the references?

Comment: Hi Google Boy..you would definitely need a dim to store your 'Agreement' attributes. But it would not hurt to store the AgreementID in your fact as it lets you relate between facts.. Not sure if this is the best practice..different arguments prevail....